# Talend DI & Windows registry interaction

Tags: registry, talend

I want to interact with Windows registry from Talend tool.

As interact action I mean *search*, *insert*, *update*, *loop* on a entry list and *delete* some keys and values.

I use Talend Data Integration tool (TIS) in Enterprise version but Open Source edition (TOS) is welcome.



Any advise to do this ?

Thanks a lot

Thomas

Comment: If you use the enterprise version you should ask Talend support directly. They might know the product better than the Stack Exchange community.

Comment: Hi @tobi6, I just asked them. But I want to submit my question to the community as answers are often different as the point of view is distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there are native components for this; but you can achieve this by using a `tSystem` component which issues a command to interact with Windows registry.
For instance, to delete a registry key you execute the command :

```
reg delete "HKCU\Some\Registry\Path" /f
```

(The path will be a parameter in your component).

Here's an example :

[image]

And the output :
[image]

Comment: Thanks @iMezouar for your answer. I ask to official Talend's support for this question. There is no dedicated component fir this king of task. They recommand to use a tSystem component as you say or to develop myself a specialized component (what I don't want to).

Comment: Additional resources: [link(]https://www.windows-commandline.com/delete-registry-key-command-line)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback :)